# Consultas entre dos valores MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

Tengo una duda con las consultas en mongoDB. Me piden contar el número de viajes que duran entre 5 y 10 minutos. No sé qué operador utilizar, he probado lo siguiente pero no obtengo resultado:

```
db.viajes.find({ $and: [{ "duracion": {$gte: 5}}, {"duracion": {$lte: 10}} ]})
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Tu consulta es correcta, pero toma en cuenta que eso devuelve un objeto de tipo `cursor`, que posee diferentes [métodos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html), entre los cuales se encuentra [`count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count). Si deseas obtener la cantidad de documentos de dicha consulta sólo debes hacer algo como: `let cantidad = db.viajes.find({$and: [...]}).count()`. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta es correcta, pero toma en cuenta que eso devuelve un objeto de tipo cursor, que posee diferentes [métodos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html), entre los cuales se encuentra [`count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count).

**Usando `cursor.count()`**

Si deseas obtener la cantidad de documentos de dicha consulta sólo debes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```js
let cantidad = db.viajes.find({$and: [...]}).count();
print(cantidad);
```

(He omitido el `Array` que pasas al operador `$and`)

Como se observa simplemente he añadido el método `count()` después de `find()` y el resultado se lo asigno a una variable.

También dispones el método [`size()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.size/#cursor.size) del objeto `cursor` que devuelve el número de documentos que tiene el cursor luego de aplicar alguno de los métodos: [`cursor.skip()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#cursor.skip) o [`cursor.limit()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit).

**Usando `db.collection.countDocuments(<query>, <options>)`**

Otra forma en la que puedes obtener el resultado sería usando el método [`countDcouments()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) directamente sobre la colección de `viajes`. Por ejemplo:

```js
let cantidad = db.viajes.countDocuments({$and: [...]});
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias, todo resuelto! Es que no me devolvía nada pero haciendo `.count()` me devuelve 0.